# update/reinstall package fails on RedHat

Tags: rhel

I am attempting to reinstall bcftools on a RedHat server, updating from bcftools version 1.10 to at least 1.14:

`cat /etc/redhat-release`

gives

`Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)`

`bcftools --version` yields

```
bcftools 1.10.2
Using htslib 1.10.2
Copyright (C) 2019 Genome Research Ltd.
License Expat: The MIT/Expat license
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

so I know that `bcftools` is already installed.

I attempted to update:

```
user@server:~$ sudo yum update bcftools
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Package(s) bcftools available, but not installed.
No packages marked for update
```

which obviously didn't work.

when I attempt to update

```
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package bcftools.x86_64 0:1.9-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libhts.so.2()(64bit) for package: bcftools-1.9-3.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package htslib.x86_64 0:1.9-5.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

========================================================================================================
 Package                  Arch                   Version                     Repository            Size
========================================================================================================
Installing:
 bcftools                 x86_64                 1.9-3.el7                   epel                 609 k
Installing for dependencies:
 htslib                   x86_64                 1.9-5.el7                   epel                 343 k

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+1 Dependent package)

Total download size: 953 k
Installed size: 2.6 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
(1/2): bcftools-1.9-3.el7.x86_64.rpm                                             | 609 kB  00:00:00     
(2/2): htslib-1.9-5.el7.x86_64.rpm                                               | 343 kB  00:00:00     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                   1.3 MB/s | 953 kB  00:00:00     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : htslib-1.9-5.el7.x86_64                                                              1/2 
  Installing : bcftools-1.9-3.el7.x86_64                                                            2/2 
  Verifying  : bcftools-1.9-3.el7.x86_64                                                            1/2 
  Verifying  : htslib-1.9-5.el7.x86_64                                                              2/2 

Installed:
  bcftools.x86_64 0:1.9-3.el7                                                                           

Dependency Installed:
  htslib.x86_64 0:1.9-5.el7                                                                             

Complete!
```

but the same bcftools old version 1.10.2 is showing afterward.

How can I update bcftools?

Comment: Is it possible that the old version of bcftools was installed by a means other than yum/rpm and your PATH is just favoring 1.10? `which bcftools` should show you where the 1.10 one is being executed from. `rpm -ql bcftools` will list out the files that the rpm installed. On my rhel 7.9 system the rpm installs the executable to `/usr/bin/bcftools`.

Comment: For what it's worth though, the RPM you're installing, which appears to be the latest available RPM for bcftools for RHEL7 is bcftools 1.9, so it's actually older than the version you're running. You may want to try building/installing from the source https://github.com/samtools/bcftools/releases/ to get a more update to date version

Comment: Nowhere in your output I see a newer version of this package. Are you sure it's in the repos you're using?

Comment: I'm just going based on the version that is getting installed in your output. `bcftools-1.9-3.el7.x86_64.rpm`. That is the same RPM that gets installed on my system. When I run `bcftools --version` it outputs `bcftools 1.9`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the version you want is not yet available in the repository. Maybe this can help you:

[RedHat/CentOS dependencies:](https://github.com/samtools/bcftools/blob/b866bd74f3ccf89e036ae74663519339035e83a9/INSTALL#L218)

```bsh
sudo yum install -y autoconf automake make gcc perl-Data-Dumper zlib-devel bzip2 bzip2-devel xz-devel curl-devel openssl-devel bsdtar wget
```

```bsh
wget -qO- https://github.com/samtools/bcftools/releases/download/1.15/bcftools-1.15.tar.bz2 | bsdtar -xvf- -C /tmp/
cd /tmp/bcftools-1.15
make install
ln -s /usr/local/bin/bcftools /bin/bcftools
bcftools --version
```

I hope it's useful.